# How can I convert a string slugify in the equivalent in human

Tags: javascript, node.js, slugify

I want transform a string that it is slugified in another string that it is the equivalent in human readable?

I take the parametesr from an url:

```
bookmark/10/disco%20asdasd
```

So I have the nome that is "disco%20asdasd". But in this way it not confrontable so I need to convert "disco%20asdasd" in "disco asdasd" that is the operation opposite to slugify. Anyone can help me?

Comment: I don't know if you want, but I presume you do since you're asking here :) Wording apart, this is not a code writing service. You should edit the question and post sample data (input and output) together with the code you've got so far and explanations of where you're stuck.

Comment: So you don't need slugify - you need URL decoding. See [my updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908645/how-can-i-convert-a-string-slugify-in-the-equivalent-in-human/42908749#42908645) below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would really help if you showed an example of a string that you want to convert and an example of a string that you want to convert it to. Without that I can only recommend you some general solutions. See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/slug
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugg
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-up-string
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/speakingurl
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/sluggin
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-slug
- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/slug

See the code examples in the docs of those projects.

### Update

If you want to convert: `disco%20asdasd` to: `disco asdasd` then use:

```
let decoded = decodeURI(yourString);
```

or:

```
let decoded = decodeURIComponent(yourString);
```

but this is not a slug - this is URI-encoding and decoding.

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

More info on Wikipedia:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding